# How to update state for all inputs using functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble wording my question, so hopefully I can explain it well enough here!

I'm making a generic form component, which handles form validation on the top level. The end result would look like this:

```
<Form action='/api/endpoint'>
    ... form inputs go here
</Form>
```

Everything is working really well. If I go through and fill out the form, I can submit it just fine and the validation works.

The form has state which looks like this:

```
{
    values: { name: 'Johnny', age: 18, email: 'email@example.com' },
    used: { name: true, age: true, email: true },
    validators: { name: (Yup Validator), age: (Yup Validator), email: (Yup Validator) }
}
```

The state is populated using custom onChange and onBlur functions in each of the components (they are passed using react context). For example, onBlur the `used` part of the state is updated to `true` for the current element, onChange the `values` part of the state is updated to the elements value, etc.

As aforementioned, this works well when I go through and use every element. What I want to happen is that when the user clicks the `Submit` button, it checks *EVERY* field to ensure it's valid before sending the POST request.

An easy solution I thought to do would be to just programmatically blur every element which calls the onBlur function. However, because setState is asynchronous, it only adds the last element to the state (because it's being overridden, if that makes sense).

I'm wondering if I can either modify how I'm setting my form state *or* if there's a way I can wait before setting the form state again.

I'm using functional components, and I know that useEffect exists for this purpose, but I'm not sure how to use it in my situation.

Here's how I'm setting the state onChange and onBlur:

```
  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setFormState({...formState, used: {...formState.used, [e.target.name]: true}});
  }
```

(hopefully you can infer onChange from that, it's the same but with `values` instead of `used`)

My idea of blurring everything was as follows:

```
  const blurAll = async () => {
    let inputs = [];

    // Get all inputs on the current page
    const inputTags = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    // Get all text areas (because they are <textarea> instead of <input>)
    const textAreas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
    // Concat the arrays
    inputs.push(...inputTags, ...textAreas);

    // Trigger a blur event for each (to initialize them in formstate)
    inputs.map(input => { input.focus(); input.blur(); });
  }
```

However because setFormState uses the existing form state, it all happens too fast and so only the last element is added to the state.

I understand that this blurAll is probably not a great solution, but I was just trying to get something working (and then I was going to get only the inputs in the form itself).

This leads me to my question, how do I wait for the previous setState to complete before setting the state again (in the case on my onChange and onBlur)?

OR is there a way in JavaScript to simply update one key in my state object instead of replacing the entire object?

If you need any more information, comment and I'll provide as much as I can. I'd prefer not to use a form library, I'm trying to learn React, and this seemed like a good thing to further my knowledge! Thank you!